# Embedding Flash Movie in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, flash

I would like to embed a Flash Movie in  WPF Applicaion. preferably via the activeX control that is also used in internet explorer.

additionally i want to get and send parameters to this flash movie.

i am using VC# express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used 'AxShockwaveFlashObjects' library to play flash(.swf) files

Comment: download Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll

Comment: thank you! i have imported the two dlls into the references. but i dont see anything in the toolbox. how can i add a control to my window?

Comment: i have also added the macromedia flash object factory to the toolbox, but i still dont see any control there.

Comment: right click on ToolBox-->Choose Items-->COM Components-->(there select shockwaveflashobject object if ur not finding then browse dll u'll get)

Comment: to get shockwaveflas object in com components go to 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash' there 'flash9c.ocx' should be there register that as dll i.e., using regsvr32, now do the above commented process

Comment: if ur not finding flash9c.ocx then download it from net and register that